# Show popover from CGRect of button

Tags: iphone

I created a button programmatically to be added to the rightBarButtonItem.  I had to create a few buttons in the upper right with the UINavigationController, so I put them in a containerView, and then, put that as the right barButtonItem customView in the init method.  If my button and containerView are declared like this:

```
UIButton *filterButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(49, 0, 44, 44)];
[filterButton setTitle:@"Filter" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[filterButton addTarget:self action:@selector(FilterButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 248, 44)];
```

How do I get the popover to present from the filterButton rect?  My method looks like this so far, but it is not correct.

```
- (IBAction)FilterButtonPressed:(id)sender {
// other code
    [self.FilterPopover presentPopoverFromRect:button.superview.bounds inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I display popover usually like this:

```
 [self.FilterPopover presentPopoverFromRect:button.bounds inView:button permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```